# Keep position of div with overflow same on resize?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, positioning

Im currently trying to tweak a image slider ive been working on. What I'm trying to do is keep the same position of the slider where it meets the left side of the browser when a user resizes there browser. Check the example below

```
            +------------------------+
            |          body          |
+--------------------------------------------------+
|           |                                      |
|           |<- Keep this aligned at the same      |
|           |    position on browser resize?       |
|           |                                      |
|           |                                      |
|           |                                      |
+--------------------------------------------------+
            |                        |
            +------------------------+


HTML:
<div id="scrollerWrapper">
    <div id="imageScroller">
        <img class="i" href="..." />
        <img class="i" href="..." />
        <img class="i" href="..." />
        <img class="i" href="..." />
    </div>
</div>

    browserHeight = parseInt($(window).height(), 10);

    galleryMargin = browserHeight * 0.025;
    imageHeight = browserHeight - 80 - (galleryMargin * 2);
    if (imageHeight < 250) {
        imageHeight = 250;
    }
    $(".i").css("height", imageHeight + "px");
```

Comment: Is your `js` code in `window.load` or `window.resize`?

Comment: window.resize is inside $(window).load()

Comment: what does the CSS look like for the scrollwrapper?

Comment: Create jsfiddle.net example please.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can get more detailed with your question, what I understood from what you explained looks like this and doesnt needs any javascript yet

the fiddle is here http://jsfiddle.net/caramba/LzwUP/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
* { padding:0px; margin:0px; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="position:absolute;width:100%;height:400px;background-color:orange;">
        <div style="position:relative;left:0px;top:100px;width:500px;height:200px;background-color:navy;"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```